# Why am I getting a null value on a hash map passed to freemarker when it isnt null?

Tags: java, freemarker

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 port(8080);

 Configuration config  = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_26);
 config.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("PATH_NAME"));



 get("/test", (req,res) ->{
     StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
     Template temp = config.getTemplate("loginform.ftl");
     temp.process(null, writer);
     return writer;
 });


 post("/select", (req,res) -> {
      String city = req.queryParams("city");
      String state = req.queryParams("state");


      Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

      data.put("Hello", "Your not null!");

      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      Template temp = config.getTemplate("result.ftl");

      temp.process(data, writer);

      return writer;

     });

}
```

Above is the main method to the Spark application i am developing. It involves two templates, loginform.ftl and result.ftl. Loginform.ftl is a simple html form that sends a post request to the server which handled by the post handler in the code above. When I fill out the form and send the request, i get a 500 internal server error. The error relates to the result.ftl which, right now, i am using to test template making. I am passing a HashMap to the result.ftl template. The error i get is:

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> data  [in template "result.ftl" at line 2, column 8]


FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list data as key, value  [in template "result.ftl" at line 

2, column 1]
----
```

I took this to mean that data was null when the template was being generated , but it very clearly isn't. I have no idea this is happening. My template files are below.
loginform.ftl

```
<form action= "/select" method= "POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

  City Name: <input type= "text"  name = "city">

  State(2 letter format):<input type= "text"  name = "state">

  <input type= "submit" id = "submitButton">

</form>
```

result.ftl

```
<html>
  <#list data as key, value>
   ${key} = ${value};
  </#list>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the freemaker version are you using ? Suppose you refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821329/freemarker-and-hashmap-how-do-i-get-key-value). it may be helpful.

Comment: I am using version 2.3.25

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freemarker template error: null or missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223840/freemarker-template-error-null-or-missing)

Comment: This is the 2nd duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223840/freemarker-template-error-null-or-missing/...